# how do I dynamically render layout based on dropdown filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a simple layout where the user can choose a dynamic dropdown that retrieves data based on an API call using React.js and Django as backend, but however, I want to pre-render category from the database and let the user choose which Industry, and change the layout data accordingly

```
async function fetchFeed(domain) {
    return api.get(`http://localhost:8002/api/v1/xxxx/list/?domain=${domain}`);
}

async function fetchDomain() {
    return api.get('http://localhost:8002/api/v1/xxxx/domain/'); # return all domains
}


export default function Board () {
    const [isModalOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
     const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
     const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState([])
     const [domains, setDomains] = useState([]);

    // fetches data
    const fetchData = (domain) => {
      fetchFeed(domain)
      .then((response)=>{
          setResponseData(response.data.results)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
      })
    }   
    
     const handleOnClick = async (data) => {
        try {
           setUsers(data);
   
           // Now that the data has been fetched, open the modal
           setModalIsOpen(true);
         } catch (err) {
           console.error("failed", err);
         }
     };
   
     useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, []);
     return (
      <div className="container content">
          <select>options</select>
      {responseData.map((data) => (
        <div className="col" key={data.t_id}>
          <div className="row">{data.tactic_name}</div>
            {data.data.map((item) => (
              <div className="row" key={item._id} onClick={() => handleOnClick(item)}><span>{item.title}</span></div>
            ))}
        </div>
      ))}
      {isModalOpen && <Modal onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} data={users}/> }
      </div>
     );
   }
```

Comment: Is the code what you have tried? What is or isn't working?

Comment: @gptt916 this is what I Have tried

Comment: And what isn't working? What errors are you getting?